# Closed form for $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{(2^k-1)^a}$

Tags: summation, special-functions, closed-form, polygamma

Is there a closed form for
$$f(a)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2^k-1)^a},$$
where $0<a\in\mathbb{R}$.

My attempts so far have considered $a\in\mathbb{N}$, which appears to give finite sums of the [q-Polygamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html), e.g.

$$f(4)=\frac{\psi _{\frac{1}{2}}^{(3)}(1)}{6 \log ^42}+\frac{\psi _{\frac{1}{2}}^{(2)}(1)}{\log ^32}+\frac{11 \psi _{\frac{1}{2}}^{(1)}(1)}{6 \log ^22}+\frac{\psi _{\frac{1}{2}}^{(0)}(1)}{\log 2}-1.$$

"Closed form" here could be an integral, or something akin to hypergeometric functions.

**Update:** The [Erdős–Borwein constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Borwein_constant) is related.